# Android Generic Parameter

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, rx-java2

Hi guys i have some problem passing parameter. I have 2 API call and if the device has no internet connection i need to pass the call back to another class
because each api has different pojo the android give me warning mismatch type. Heres my code

```
 override fun initRetrofitCarList(call: Observable<Response<MyCarModel>>) {
    compositeDisposable.add(call
            .map{
              it.body()
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                if (it.status == Constants.Result.SUCCESS) {
                    mPresenter.successGetVehicleList(it.vehicle, "api")
                } else {
                    mPresenter.failedGetVehicleList(it.message)
                }
            }, {
                mPresenter.onNoConnection(call) <- this here will give WARNING because of mismatch type
            }))
}

override fun initRetrofitBikeList(call: Observable<Response<MyBikeModel>>) {
    compositeDisposable.add(call
             .map{
              it.body()
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                if (it.status == Constants.Result.SUCCESS) {
                    mPresenter.successGetVehicleList(it.vehicle, "api")
                } else {
                    mPresenter.failedGetVehicleList(it.message)
                }
            }, {
                mPresenter.onNoConnection(call) <- this here will give WARNING because of mismatch type
            }))
}
```

How to make the parameter of the function take generic call ?

EDIT

```
 override fun onNoConnection(//need to be generic) {
    mView.dismissProgressDialog()
    mView.showRetryDialog(call)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare the function will recieve generic by putting T before function name,
showRetryDialog function must also be generic, or else typecast generic to expected type (unsafe typecast)

```
override fun <T> onNoConnection(call :Observable<Response<T>>){
            mView.dismissProgressDialog()
            mView.showRetryDialog(call)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're defining your call differently on both methods:

· In `initRetrofitCarList()` call is `Observable<Response<MyCarModel>>`

· In `initRetrofitBikeList()` call is `Observable<Response<MyBikeModel>>`

Therefore when you pass this call on to another function, you need to request the generic `Observable<Response<T>>` as parameter.

Comment: i edited my question it just showing retry dialog and the dialog has button for retry api and if the user click the button it will retry the call

Comment: As Ramees pointed out, the right parameter for `onNoConnection()` is `Observable<Response<T>>`